# blur edges of 9-patch image of editbox

Tags: android, nine-patch

i have generated nine patch image using [9-Patch generator](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html)

but its not showing desired result  , following is my core image and i have use this in a 9-patch image generator.

[image: base image]

current result is

[image: current result]

desired result is

[image]

you can clearly see the difference that edges of 9 patched image is quite thin and blur. how do i resolve it

**Edits**

**Region**

[image]

**Padding**

[image]

**Optical**

[image]

Comment: you have to design 9-patch image for all resolutions and place in drawables. one 9-patch will not do good.

Comment: yes available for all resolution as i said i have used 9-patch generator and all images are named as `edittext_bg.9`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, while generating 9-patch image all the curves are not selected.
**Check out the below image.**

[image]

Also before downloading there is option "**Interactive Preview**", check it out as per the name it will show how your image will show for your current selection.

Comment: you can view my edits , there is not any change in generator

Comment: have you checked interactive preview ?

Comment: I successfully created 9-Patch with by using region option.

Comment: creation is not an issue , issue is when it actually appears on screen you can see the edges are pretty blur

Comment: My point is, if you made any mistake while generating image, it appear blur.

Comment: you can see the attached images in my question , did you find any issue ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129449/discussion-between-nakul-and-hunt).

Comment: Hi I have only used option region and it worked, Not able so find any mistake in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a reason to go for 9 patch png mess for simple layouts like this. 
You can easily achieve it using a drawable and set it as background for your EditText.

Use the below code for your drawable, eg. blue_border.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape>
        <corners android:radius="4dp" />
        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#2979ff"/>
        <solid android:color="@color/colorWhite"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

Use the above blue_border.xml as background to EditText in main layout.

```
<EditText
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:maxLength="10"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_layout_ex"
        android:hint="Mobile Number"/>
```

The outcome you'll get from above code:
[image]

You can always change the border color, width, background or corner radius by changing the attributes in your drawable blue_border.xml.